# link data to one master file but then be able to manipulate the master file at same time as the individual sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I saw there are several ways to aggregate multiple sheets into one master file, but I'm struggling to find a way where you aggregate data into one master file but also be able to manipulate the master file too after all information has been gathered.

I was wondering, does a tool like this in google sheets exist? If yes, could somebody guide me to it and I will try it out from there and if not, can another program be used to achieve that?

Currently, I tried query function, and it has achieved aggregating data onto one sheet, but now I want to find a way to manipulate the master sheet without getting errors or changing in the individual sheets

Comment: you can do so but only to such an extent to not create a paradox

Comment: having master sheet with imported data from slave sheet any changes in slave sheet will be automatically reflected in master sheet while any changes in master sheet which would change data in slave sheet are not allowed because it would create a loop paradox